# SSD read or write issue dual boot windows and ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, ssd

I installed ubuntu dual boot with windows 11 (firstly pc has only windows 11), every time i turn off system and boot, if i go directly to ubuntu from boot selection menu my ssd's have no access to write(eg- create a new folder inside ssd is blacked/unable to click.. but if i boot to windows first then again reboot to boot selection menu then boot to ubuntu then ssd write works.. any way to fix this???

also i have created a favourite folder on quick access in ubuntu(folder actually inside my ssd) it can't access directly from first boot i have to goto the folder from file manager first to get favourite quick access work, is tat normal????

Comment: Could be a read-only filesystem from improper shutdown.  In a terminal, type mount  and look for the line with "on /" in it.  Following the filesystem type, are the options. do they start (rw,... or (ro,... ro is read-only, and results from filesystem or disk problems.

Comment: This sounds like a common Windows issue when "rebooting into Ubuntu", which leaves some hardware in an unclean state. It may be better to do a complete shutdown, *then* boot into Ubuntu. It will be important to confirm that Fast Boot is disabled as well.

Comment: That's why disabling the Windows' Fast Startup feature is a must.